# find each in ruby increase the speed of query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I wanted to delete around 5 million or more records daily from our database which are actually expired users.

I have used "find_each" batch process to delete these records, but its taking 1 day to delete only 1 million records, so it will take 5 days to delete 5 million records :( which is too much time consuming.

Is there any quick way to safe delete millions of records from database in ruby.

here is my code :

```
now = Date.today
@expired_users = ExportUser.where("status != ? and DTSysModified >= ? and DTSysModified <= ?", "Active", Date.new(now.year, 04, 1),  Date.new(now.year, 04, -1))

@expired_users.find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |user|
  user.destroy!
end
```

Comment: are there any call backs on the deletion of user.?

Comment: @Athar, no there are no call backs.

Comment: then answer given below is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class) will do the job faster then you can think:

```
@expired_users.delete_all
```

Use [`destroy`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy) only if you want to execute all associated callback while deleting the object.

Comment: delete_all, will delete in one shot right. is it safe to use this for deleting millions of records?  Thanks for your valuable solution :)

Comment: If you don't have callbacks to fire while deleting - this is the best way to perform such operation. Deleting like his millions of records is as safe as to delete 10 records :)

Comment: Ok, let me try with this. Thanks again :)